# Two different Intel xeon e5 24xx on one dual-socket motherboard

Tags: xeon, multiprocessing

Can I use two different e5 24xx on one dual socket motherboard or must the CPU's be identical?

Comment: Why downvoting a completely valid question? Not everyone knows if you can do this or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just don't do this.

It doesn't matter what the silly reason or specific circumstance is... Either use *one* processor or two *identical* processors.

See: [Is it possible to influence the way CPUs are enumerated under Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/618974/is-it-possible-to-influence-the-way-cpus-are-enumerated-under-linux/618977#618977)

and: [Can I mix two cpus with a different clock speed on a board?](https://serverfault.com/questions/420312/can-i-mix-two-cpus-with-a-different-clock-speed-on-a-board/420314#420314)

Comment: This really isn't as big a deal as you make it seem. Intel even documents this, and lists which CPUs support it: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-5500-vol-1-datasheet.html

Comment: But there's no _good_ reason to do it.

Comment: No one asked if it was a good idea. They just asked if it was supported. And it is.

Comment: I give you a good reason to do this: you have 2 different CPU's and you don't want to throw one of them to dustbin.

Comment: Has anything changed since 2014 by any chance? Are the new Scalable Xeons better for mixing different models of them? At least, the operational frequency and voltage seems to be adjustable as far as I can tell (SpeedStep feature).

Comment: @user2173353 Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @ewwhite Because you might buy a server model with only one CPU installed and then want to add a second CPU from an other model that isn't identical. Or because you don't have the budget to buy an identical CPU. It could be many things. It would be handy to not have to match the processor exactly. But if it causes so many problems, maybe it is not worth it. I was just wondering if anything had changed or is expected to change in those problems. Because, being able to mix processors without issues would be a nice feature, I think.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can. Intel says in their Xeon Datasheets that you only need to match  the:

- Intel QuickPath Interconnect frequency
- core frequency
- power segment
- internal cache sizes.

Also, they state "Mixing components operating at different internal clock frequencies is not supported and will not be validated by Intel. Combining processors from different power segments is also not supported."

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e5-1600-2600-vol-1-datasheet.html (page 165)

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e5-v3-datasheet-vol-1.html (page 28)

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-5500-vol-1-datasheet.html (page 25)

Comment: But why would anyone do this? You're overlooking the practicality, supportability and business reasons that argue against it.

Comment: @ewwhite I'm not overlooking those reasons, I'm just leaving them up to the reader to take into consideration.